# Polynomial approximation to the sigmoid function

Tags: polynomials, machine-learning

Is there any polynomial approximation to the sigmoid function $ 1/(1 + e^{-x}) $?

The sigmoid curve also known as s-curve is used to shows the sales statistics. It is ideally expected that the sales curve follows the s-curve over a fiscal year, but that doesn't always hold true in the real world. The month-wise data when plotted, somewhat resembles a sigmoid curve. But the same when plotted for week-wise data, lot of fluctuations come up, and the resulting plot doesn't look like that for a sigmoid curve.
To show how it should look ideally, $y1$ is the month-wise data, and I need to fit week-wise datapoints to the sigmoid curve. It should also hold true that the sum of the sales for the four weeks in a month should be equal to the month-wise data. So given the month-wise sale, I am trying to predict the sales of each week such that the sum of the sales of the four weeks in a month is equal to the sales of that month.

Comment: Check this out: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+polynomial+for+1%2F%281%2Be%5E-x%29

Comment: You may want to make this more precise: *Where* do you want to approximate, and how do you measure "approximation"? On a bounded interval, with uniform norm or unbounded interval, in some (weighted) $L_1-$ or $L_2-$ norm, or what? Uniform norm on the whole real line won't work, or have you heard of a polynomial $\to1$ as $x\to\infty$ (different from $1$, naturally)?

Comment: What I want to do is fit four consecutive points $x_1, x_1+1, x_1+2, x_1+3$ to the sigmoid function such that $1/(1 + e^{-x_1}) + 1/(1 + e^{-x_1 - 1}) +1/(1 + e^{-x_1 - 2}) +1/(1 + e^{-x_1 -3 })$ is equal to or at least close to a fixed value $y_1$. So I thought if polynomial approximation would work for this. Do you have any suggestion to solve this?

Comment: So I want to find $x_1$, when $y_1$ is known

Comment: By curiosity, why do you want to make this approximation?

Comment: Please, add any background/motivation *to the body* of your question. Comments may be deleted at any time with or without notice by people enjoying that privilege. And don't forget to mention why this is a problem for you at all.

Comment: I have added the background/motivation for clarity

Comment: Page 5 of https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/074.pdf may help you!